# What is HTTP caching in iPhone for caching images

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, httprequest

What is HTTP caching in iPhone and how it helps in caching images? How does it handles the image refreshing?

I will be having image URL with me. I was planning to use HTTPRequest and then saving the image in my file system. Then came across this term "HTTP Caching".

Please explain.

Comment: Check out HJCache, built to make loading and caching images especially easy for iOS apps.
http://www.markj.net/hjcache-iphone-image-cache/